# How to import owl classes into the eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, class, owl

I want to import and list semantic web (owl) file's classes into the eclipse. I did import pellet and protege library my eclipse program but still I see force close my android project. nothing red line or wrong code because I used same codes in net beans. my codes  is below..

```
public static final IRI localLocation_IRI = IRI.create("file:c:///rdfex.owl");
public static final IRI Ont_Base_IRI = IRI.create("http://www.emkarhafriyat.com/owlex.owl");
    OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLDataFactory f = OWLManager.getOWLDataFactory();
    OWLOntology o = null;
    public void testAddAxioms() {
        try {
            o = m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(Ont_Base_IRI);
            OWLClass clsA = f.getOWLClass(IRI.create(Ont_Base_IRI + "#ClassA"));
            OWLClass clsB = f.getOWLClass(IRI.create(Ont_Base_IRI + "#ClassB"));
            // Now create the axiom
            OWLAxiom ax1 = f.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(clsA, clsB);
            // add the axiom to the ontology.
            AddAxiom addAxiom1 = new AddAxiom(o, ax1);
            // We now use the manager to apply the change
            m.applyChange(addAxiom1);
            // print all classes
            for (OWLClass cls : o.getClassesInSignature()) {
               EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
               edit.setText((CharSequence) cls);
            }
            m.removeOntology(o);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            edit.setText("Not successfull");
        }
    }
```

I have mistake this code segment

```
public static final IRI localLocation_IRI = IRI.create("file:c:///rdfex.owl");
public static final IRI Ont_Base_IRI = IRI.create("http://www.emkarhafriyat.com/owlex.owl");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no ontology in the URL http://www.emkarhafriyat.com/owlex.owl (404) therefore nothing can be loaded by `m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(Ont_Base_IRI);` and you get an error.

To fix it, you should either expose your OWL file at the specified URL or to load the OWL file from local. You can do it this way:

```
//Create the file object
File file = new File("/your/local/path/example.owl");
// Now load the local copy of the ontology     
OWLOntology yourOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer but I didnt do neither local path, nor URL. local path should be phones path ?

Comment: yes, I guess you can use the phone path (local path) to import it.